# VB6 IDE form load event slow in Win7 virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I have successfully installed Vb6 on a virtual machine Win7 32-bit.
The compilation and execution of various projects done faster. There are problems at runtime in debug mode (F5). Many seconds to display the first form.

To exclude problems caused by third-party libraries I've created a small test project with a single form with a single button. Running with F5 happens instantly if I do not write code in the form load event.
But if I write even a single line of code (also commented) the opening of the form takes about 30 seconds.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

PS. In the VB6.exe file properties (compatibility tab) i set the following options:

- Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3)
- Run as administrator; Disable desktop composition

Answer (score 0):

XP Compatibility, reduce colours?

Thats the only diff between your setup and mine I think.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that it is on a virtual machine, I've just edited the question. Unfortunately, "reduce colours" doesn't solve the problem